# Problema al instalar @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

Estoy teniendo un conflicto al querer instalar @reduxjs/toolkit el cual es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con respecto a la version de react realice el `npm list react` y todas las dependencias me dicen que utilizan la version 16.14 de react.
A que otro problema puede ser que se deba que no pueda instalar redux en mi proyecto?

Tambien intente instalar la version 1.8.3 especifica de reduxjs/toolkit y tengo el error de nuevo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un conflicto entre dependencias y te lo está explicando bien claro.

No, no estás usando react 16 en todas partes y ese es precísamente el problema.

Ahi dice que esa versión de react-native que intentas usar pide react `^18.2.0`, react-redux `8.0.5` pide react-native `>=0.59`, tu `@reduxjs/toolkit` pide un react-redux `^7.2.1`. Por lo tanto, npm no tiene forma de buscar versiones de esas librerías que funcionen bien entre sí con esas restricciones.

Sí miras el `package.json` para la versión 8.0.5, los peerDependencies son bien estrictos

```
peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "react": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.59",
    "redux": "^4"
  },
```

Si miras el [`package.json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux/v/7.2.9?activeTab=code) de la librería para v7.2.9 , vas a ver que react-native era opcional sin más y por eso no generaba conflicto. Entonces, o te subes a una versión más moderna de react en el proyecto o bajas react-redux a v7

Comment: Intente instalar tambien la version 1.8.3 de reduxjs/toolkit pero el error sigue estando, hasta que version deberia bajar de reduxjs/toolkit para que me permita instalar la dependencia? Si no lo mas facil seria actualizar React pero podria tener conflictos con las otras dependencias tengo entendido. Ahi agregue algo en la publicacion, gracias por responder

Comment: O puedo instalar una version 1.8.3 de reduxjs/toolkit si antes instalo una version 7.2.9 de react-redux para no tener conflictos?

Comment: @alejandromartin Lee los logs que nos estás mostrando. Esas dos versiones de reduxjs/toolkit tienen el mismo peerOptional de react-redux.